# trying to create a loop function to sum random variables in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Please see below my code for trying to run a loop of 10000 iterations, every time the code loops I want it to select a new value for my two random variables labelled: `premium_A_1` and `cost_of_claim`.

```
for (i in 1:10000){

  profit_A_scheme1 = c()
  premium_A_scheme1=sample(c(200,170,140), size = 1, replace = TRUE, prob = s.d_scheme1) 
  costclaim_A= runif(1, 0, 400)
  profit_A_scheme1[i] = premium_A_scheme1 - costclaim_A
  
}
```

The code returns `profit_A_scheme_1 = (NA, NA, ..., x)` when I was hoping for `profit_A_scheme_1 = (x1, x2, ..., xn)`. Essentially only assigning a value to the final loop and `NA` for every loop previous. In case anyone tries to run this code the probabilities for the premium r.v. are `prob = (0.4510610, 0.3207926, 1 - 0.4510620 - 0.3207926)`.

Thanks for any help you are able to offer as I've been stuck on this for a minute now.

Comment: You're setting `profit_A_scheme1 = c()` in every loop, the initialisation should be done before the loop. Because R is vectorised, the whole code can be written as `premium_A_scheme1=sample(c(200,170,140), size = 10000, replace = TRUE, prob = s.d_scheme1)` `costclaim_A= runif(10000, 0, 400)` `profit_A_scheme1 <- premium_A_scheme1 - costclaim_A`

Answer (score 0):

Try (replace `prob =abs(rnorm(3)/100)` with your own) :

```
for (i in 1:10000){
  
  profit_A_scheme1 = NULL
  premium_A_scheme1=sample(c(200,170,140), size = 1, replace = TRUE, prob =abs(rnorm(3)/100)) 
  costclaim_A= runif(1, 0, 400)
  profit_A_scheme1 = premium_A_scheme1 - costclaim_A
  print(profit_A_scheme1)
  
}
```